# Custom tabs: styling tabs through styles.xml

Tags: android

I am trying to style my tabs through styles.xml. Here is my code:

```
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.style.tabsel_bg_style);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.style.tab_bg_style);
```

And in styles.xml:

```
<style name="tabsel_bg_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/tabsel_bg_style1</item>
</style>


<style name="tabsel_bg_style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bg_img</item>
</style>

<style name="tab_bg_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/tab_bg_style1</item>
</style>


<style name="tab_bg_style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
      <item name="android:background">@color/White</item>
```

But I am getting exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0002
```

I know It's simple but not getting idea exactly where I am going wrong?

Comment: `Theme.Holo` is not available on devices with Android 2.3 and older. You should move these styles in the *values-v11* folder if you plan to support these.

Comment: I tried moving styles to values-v11 folder too, but still i am getting same Fatal Exception of Resources$NotFoundException.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for `setBackgroundResource(int resId)` is supposed to be the ID of a **Drawable**, not a style.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_img);
```

As far as I know, there is no way to apply a style to an element outside of the XML layout. If you created the View by code, you can use the third argument of the constructor to set the default style.

```
public View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   ...
}
```